# Is there any way to format multi-line chart tooltips to a single-line?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I have a multiple-series chart (lines and area range type).
Chart image

[image]

I want to format the tooltip so that instead of having:

```
POSITIVE: 20%
POSITIVE RANGE: 19% - 21%
NEGATIVE: 45%
NEGATIVE RANGE: 43% - 46%
NEUTRAL: 35%
NEUTRAL RANGE: 34% - 36%
```

Format it to:

```
POSITIVE: 20% (19% - 21%)
NEGATIVE: 45% (43% - 46%)
NEUTRAL: 35% (34% - 36%)
```

I need it to be a SHARED tooltip, since there are many data in the chart.

I have tried to giving `id` and `relatedid` to each series, but wasn't able to achieve changing the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `formatter` function for the tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function(e) {
        var points = this.points,
            i,
            result = '';

        function formatPoint(p, low, high) {
            return '<span style="color:' + p.point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + p.series.name + ': <b>' + p.point.y + '% (' + low + '% -' + high + ' %)</b><br/>'
        }

        for (i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
            result += formatPoint(points[i], points[i + 1].point.low, points[i + 1].point.high)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g3qeobaf/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thanks!! It worked perfect! On the xaxis I have dates, and I would like to add it at the top of the tooltip, I tried: 


                return   Highcharts.dateFormat('%b - %Y',
                                          new Date(p.x)) +' <span style="color:' + p.point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + p.series.name + ': <b>' + Math.round(p.point.y) + '% (' + Math.round(low) + '-' + Math.round(high) + ')</b><br/>'
            }

But it adds it to every row instead of just in the top

Comment: Done, can you help me with the date problem I have?

Comment: Yes, of course, just set the initial value of `result` variable: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vg5ftzx7/

Answer (score 0):

On the xaxis I have dates, and I would like to add it at the top of the tooltip, I tried:

```
            return   Highcharts.dateFormat('%b - %Y',
                                      new Date(p.x)) +' <span style="color:' + p.point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + p.series.name + ': <b>' + Math.round(p.point.y) + '% (' + Math.round(low) + '-' + Math.round(high) + ')</b><br/>'
        }
```

But it adds it to every row instead of just in the top